# What happens when a process's current working directory is deleted by another process?

Tags: process, operating-system

Same as question, what will happens when a process's current working directory is deleted by another process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The process will get an error if it tries to access a file in the working directory. It's the same as setting the current working directory to a non-existent location.